# IOS swift when keyboard apears it hiddes the top 2 TextField

Tags: ios, swift

This is my whole code when keyboard appears it hides the top 1 textfield and one is half visible. It works but when it hiddes the top fields it looks to wired.

I found this code on net but i can't able to fix it.

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, ENSideMenuDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollview: UIScrollView!

var activeTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var container_view: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Move next line to viewWillAppear functon if you store your view controllers
    self.sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.text1.delegate = self
    self.text2.delegate = self
    self.text3.delegate = self
    self.text4.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - ENSideMenu Delegate
func sideMenuWillOpen() {
    println("sideMenuWillOpen")
}

func sideMenuWillClose() {
    println("sideMenuWillClose")
}

func sideMenuDidClose() {
    println("sideMenuDidClose")
}

func sideMenuDidOpen() {
    println("sideMenuDidOpen")
}

/*
func sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu() -> Bool {
    println("sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu")
    return false
}
*/

// MARK: - Keyboard

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillBeShown:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)
}

func unregisterFromKeyboardNotifications () {
    let center:  NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    center.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

private func stopObservingKeyboardEvents() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
func keyboardWillBeShown(sender: NSNotification) {

    let info: NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    let value: NSValue = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.CGRectValue().size
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollview.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.

    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height + 80

let activeTextFieldRect: CGRect? = activeTextField?.frame
    let activeTextFieldOrigin: CGPoint? = activeTextFieldRect?.origin
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeTextFieldOrigin!)) {
        scrollview.scrollRectToVisible(activeTextFieldRect!, animated:true)
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
func keyboardWillBeHidden(sender: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    scrollview.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

// MARK: -  Text Field

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = nil
}
}
```

Comment: I personnaly use now https://cocoapods.org/pods/IQKeyboardManager , it manages the keyboard issue automatically!

Comment: The scroll view goes inside the menu bar.

Comment: That's always a danger when using stuff you don't understand.

Comment: @tomsoft is right try to use IQKEYBOARDMANAGER                       https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager&ei=TRF_njM0&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=631&ts=1442031672&sig=APONPFk4a2dp875k4uRAv97InIxdbsVPTQ. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this

```
var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height + 80
```

do this

```
self.view.frame.y -= keyboardSize.height + 80
```

(not sure what the 80 is, but I'm keeping it there in case it is accounting for something on your app.)

the .height property will stretch your frame while the .y property will move it.